# Use hiragana for name that I only know in romaji

Tags: kanji, names, hiragana

Suppose I have seen the name of a Japanese person only in romaji because all communications has been in English so far. When I want to address this person in Japanese, is it okay to write their name in hiragana only? Or is it plainly wrong? I feel it safer at least than guessing the most common kanji for that name.